# Writing key inputs to a file

Tags: c++

I'm compiling this code with GNU GCC Compiler in Code Blocks but for some reason the log file that it creates remains empty no matter what. Any ideas why this might be?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int i;
string s;

int main()
{
    ofstream log;
    log.open("log.txt");
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8)) {
        for (i=65; i<90; i++) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i)) {
                s+=i;
            }
            Sleep(10);
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE)) {
            s+=" ";
        }
    }

    log << s;
    log.close();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect `s+=i;` to do given that `s` is a string and `i` is an `int`?

Comment: Did you try just outputting *something* into the log? Like just to test put `log << "TEST";` somewhere.

Comment: Nothing get's written to the file even if i include something like log<<"TEST"

Comment: Are you looking for log.txt file in the right directory ?

Comment: What do you think is the behavior of `GetAsyncKeyState()` is?  (And, what do you expect the behavior of this program to be?)

Comment: In essence it's suppose to be a key logger. It creates the log.txt file, but it never writes anything to it.

Comment: Why are you confusing us with the GetAsyncKeyState code? Just show us the code that does `log << "TEST"`. Learn to cut your code down to minimal versions that highlight your problem.

Comment: Even if I just add the code. cout<<s; it does nooooothing

Comment: The problem seems to be that AsyncKeyState does not recogize any keys, nor does GetKeyState.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Whereas it's not very cool, `s += i` should do the right thing in this case. Because it's in the condition, `i` always is `65 <= i < 90`, which represents the characters `A` thru `Z`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Find a different way to add `i` to your string `s`

Comment: @JerryCoffin: It is the wrong type, yes. But once try: `string ("test"); int i = 66; s += i; cout << s; // output: "testB"`

Comment: @Atmocreations: You're right -- it looks like it's using an implicit conversion from int to char. Based on his later comments, the problem lies entirely elsewhere anyway (since even `log<<"TEST"` isn't working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following points:

---

Are you trying `log << "TEST"` *in* the condition?

Try this (right after the `log.open` call):

```
log.open("log.txt");
log << "TEST" << endl;
```

If `TEST` gets written to the file, your file is empty because the condition never gets true.

---

An other issue might be that the file contains non-displayable characters.
Dump your file to a hex-editor. Does the file have a size of `0` or is it containing data you might not be able to display on common text editors?

---

***EDIT: *** This should do what you want:

Either write your `i` or `" "` directly to `log` or use a stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>

//...

ofstream log;
log.open("log.txt");
stringstream str;
while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8)) {
    for (i=65; i<90; i++) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i)) {
            str << i;
        }
        Sleep(10);
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE)) {
        str << " ";
    }
}

log << str.rdbuf();
log.close();
cin.get();
```

Comment: If I test it with log << "TEST" << endl;
it works anywhere in the file even in the if's that activate if a key is pressed. The only problem now is that it wont write int i too the file. And that's kind of what I want to know, the value of the key that gets pressed

Comment: @HenningJoubert: I modified the answer and added a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

Try using  `if(GetKeyState(0x41))` instead for your `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your are looking for **log.txt** in the wrong directory